# What patterns can be used in Thunar's Select By Pattern?

Tags: search, xfce, xubuntu, selection, thunar

In Thunar, Select By Pattern - the option brought up by ctrl+s - lets you search through the files in a directory by patterns. For example, searching "?.jpg" will select all jpgs. What is the syntax of the allowed patterns? For example, is there any way to select all jpgs and pngs with this command?

Comment: I can only use one extension in one search - not multiple. I am still looking around. .https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/working-with-files-and-folders   " You can also select files by providing a pattern with the keyboard shortcut Ctrl-S or from the main menu Edit → Select pattern.... For example, to select all text files, hit Ctrl-S and enter “*.txt” in the dialog."

Comment: @John Good to know, but have you found anywhere that documents what patterns are allowed? I couldn't find anything more than you have.

Comment: Any one pattern (extension) I tried (PDF, jpg, png, .7 and like) worked just one at a time for one search. Thunar on Kali Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a thorough reading of:

https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/working-with-files-and-folders

> There are several ways to select files in Thunar.
>
> a. To select a single file, you can simply click on it with the left
> mouse button.
>
> b. You can select multiple files by holding down the Ctrl key and
> clicking on the files, or holding down the Shift key to select a range
> of files.
>
> c. You can also select multiple files and folders by using the mouse
> to drag a selection box over them. Note: If you are using View as a
> Detailed List in the Main Area, you must first position the mouse over
> a file/folder name (not in the whitespace) before dragging.
>
> **d. You can also select files by providing a pattern with the keyboard shortcut Ctrl-S or from the main menu Edit → Select
> pattern.... For example, to select all text files, hit Ctrl-S and
> enter “*.txt” in the dialog.**
>
> e. If you want to find a single file and know the beginning of the
> filename, simply start entering the filename in the view. A text box
> will appear in the bottom right corner and an incremental search will
> be performed. The first file that matches what you type will be
> selected. If there are multiple files names beginning with the same
> letters, continuing to type the name you're looking for will narrow
> your search down until the file you want is selected.

In (d) above, and in all other places I looked, and in all experiments I did, you can only select one pattern type (almost any extension or other pattern you wish.

So the answer to your question is: almost any normal pattern and the answer to the inner question:  Can I select multiple patterns?  No, that cannot be done.

Again: Thunar in Linux for my review and experiments.

Comment: But what's a pattern? Can you only do parts of filenames and file extensions that are in the "*.type" form?

Comment: I opened my BIN folder and searched for *to3 and the appropriate file was highlighted.  That is a pattern rather than an extension

Comment: Is pattern a technical term that I'm ignorant of?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Thunar used "pattern" to pick out part of a file name and it does work.

Comment: So it just means "substring of file names and their extensions"?

Comment: Yes, I think that is a reasonable observation